# Import/Export Nintex Workflow InfoPath task form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010, nintex-workflow

I'm creating a nintex workflow in my development environment, the workflow has a flexi task with a custom infopath form, but when I export/import my workflow to the staging environment the infopath form is not being exported.

Is there anyway to do this that doesn't involve creating the form again in the other environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue on SP 2013 & Nintex Workflow 2013.

Although a bit unwieldy, this works for us:

1. Create an export for the workflow in dev.
2. Go to [exportsite]/NintexWorkflows/[workflowname] and download the Infopath-form you modified
3. Import the workflow in your new environment
4. Go to [importsite]/NintexWorkflows/[workflowname] and delete the Infopath-form available there.
5. Upload the form you exported in step 2.

Now the new form should show up when you use the flexitask.

PS: I haven't tested this yet, but it might also be possible to export the entire NintexWorkflows library contents (or one subfolder for your workflow). You could use Powershell to do this quickly.